# Submitting the form using POST method also how do I get the parameters in url

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Trying to submit the form using POST method and also getting the parameters via url. While accessing website.com/profile/ it doesn't work. It returns this error message

> The GET method is not supported for route profile-list. Supported
> methods: POST.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Web.php

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}/{mobilenumber?}', [ProfileController::class, 'profileList'])->name('profile-list');
Route::post('/profile/', [ProfileController::class, 'submitForm'])->name('submit-form');
```

Blade form file

```
<form action="{{ route('submit-form') }}" method="post">
   @csrf
   ....
</form>
```

ProfileController

```
public function submitForm(Request $request) 
    {
        $request->validate(
            ...
        );

        $username = strtolower($request->input('username'));
        $mobilenumber = strtolower($request->input('mobilenumber'));

        if ($mobilenumber) {
            return redirect()->route('profile-list', ['username' => $username, 'mobilenumber' => $mobilenumber]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('profile-list', ['username' => $username]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your route definition like this

```
Route::post('/profile', 'ProfileController@submitForm')->name('submit-form');
```

and also add => @method('POST')

```
<form action="/profile" method="post">
    @method('POST')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add the params on the route you will use

```
Route::post('/profile/{username}/{mobileNumber?}', [ProfileController::class, 'submitForm'])->name('submit-form');
```

> This is because you are using the params in 'submitForm' method. This
> have not relation with the another method.

Your form

```
<form action="{{ route('submit-form', ['username' => $username, 'mobileNumber' => $mobileNumber]) }}" method="post">
   @csrf
   ....
</form>
```

> This will add the params to the route.

And finally, your handler method [PLEASE SEE THE ANOTHER IMPLEMENTATION]

```
public function submitForm(Request $request, $username, $mobileNumber = null) 
    {
        $request->validate(
            ...
        );

        $username = strtolower($username);
        // I think you dont need strtolower for the phone number

        if ($mobilenumber != null) {
            return redirect()->route('profile-list', ['username' => $username, 'mobilenumber' => $mobilenumber]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('profile-list', ['username' => $username]);
        }
    }
```

I tested after write this, and route helper works fine with null values, so a better approach is as following:

```
public function submitForm(Request $request, $username, $mobileNumber = null) 
        {
            $request->validate(
                ...
            );

        $username = strtolower($username);
        // I think you dont need strtolower for the phone number

        return redirect()->route('profile-list', ['username' => $username, 'mobilenumber' => $mobilenumber]);
    }
```